# align logo and h1 to obtain full title responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

I have a title composed of two words, the first word appears in the logo, the second I add it with a h1. How do i do to align image and h1 to get the full title and is responsive?
The result I want to get is something like this: http://i65.tinypic.com/34t9ukj.png

The html is:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="xxxxx.html">
        <img src="img/logo.jpg" id="logo" alt="logo">
        <h1 id="titolo_logo"> Abbigliamento </h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owmMed or https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PjVBKg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox, with the `a` tag as the container and `align-items: center;` to get the vertically centered alignment:

```css
#header a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="xxxxx.html">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/fb3" id="logo" alt="logo">
    <h1 id="titolo_logo"> Abbigliamento </h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

A second solution would be to make the inner items inline-blocks, with the following settings:

```css
#header a > img,
#titolo_logo{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#titolo_logo {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="xxxxx.html">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/fb3" id="logo" alt="logo"><h1 id="titolo_logo">Abbigliamento</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

The disadvantage is that in this case not the whole header area (which I assume this is supposed to be) is clickable as a link, but only the image and the `h1` themselves, whereas in the flexbox solution you can also click above and below the `h1` to open the link.